# Integrating Facebook Chat

Tags: xmpp, chat, strophe, facebook-chat

I have been asked to integrate [Facebook Chat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#Chat) to my application using JavaScript only. I cannot use X Facebook platform authentication as it needs a domain URL. So my option is to set up an [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) chat client using `strophe.js` via a digest MD5 [SASL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) mechanism.

Regarding BOSH connect manager, http://bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind. Is this enough or should I configure it in my server? I am using the [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook does not do [S2S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-server) federation, only C2S, so you will have to use that as your XMPP server (or implement something like [XEP-0100](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0100.html) at your server).  Facebook does not currently support BOSH, AFAIK.

Comment: strophe needs bosh connection manager so if facebook does not support bosh....which other javascript lib can i use??

Comment: you will have to use ur own custom bosh connection manager. Any javascript library will have to use this conn. manager if you want facebook chat to work on browser.

Comment: how do i set up my own custom connection mgr??? is there an easier way to integrate facebook chat...I hav been stuck with it for long now

Comment: You will need to use something like [punjab](https://github.com/twonds/punjab) as a connection manager.  Your connection will then operate:

client <--(BOSH)--> punjab <--(XMPP)--> facebook

Answer (score 0):

from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

> > The DIGEST-MD5 SASL mechanism is available to support traditional XMPP
> >     or multi-protocol IM clients that are
> >     not customized for (or even aware of)
> >     Facebook. This mechanism requires
> >     prompting the user for his or her
> >     password; therefore, it should only be
> >     used when necessary. In particular, it
> >     MUST NOT be used for any client that:
>
> **•Proxies the XMPP connection (the
>   connection must be directly from the
>   user's computer to Facebook).**
>
> •Reports
>   messages or any other information
>   about user activity to a third party
>   (including the client developer).
>
> •Integrates with Facebook, or has a
>   Facebook Application ID. If your
>   application does any of the above, you
>   must use Facebook Platform
>   authentication instead.

So, you can't use DIGEST-MD5 with a bosh server but you must use X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM