# Does Facebook chat platform support BOSH?

Tags: xmpp, strophe, facebook-chat, jsjac

I've read a relative question[(Integrating Facebook Chat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052780/integrating-facebook-chat) 's answer whitch said

> Facebook does not do S2S federation, only C2S, so you will have to use that as your XMPP server (or implement something like XEP-0100 at your server). Facebook does not currently support BOSH, AFAIK.

I also need to integrate Facebook Chat to my App, and I want to know if they support XMPP over BOSH now? There is only one page about Chat API at developers.facebook.com, I didn't see BOSH things.

If they don't support BOSH, what should I do? Do I need a server with BOSH to be a proxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't support BOSH. But you can run your own BOSH connection manager like Punjab to connect to Facebook over BOSH over your BOSH proxy.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, I'm going to play with node-xmpp-bosh for a try.